# Import css and js to spring mvc jsp page

Tags: css, spring, jsp

I have added following configurations, but it wont apply the css and js. Is there anythy i need to add other than these

Config.xml

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

jspfile

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>


<spring:url value="/resources/css/metro.css" var="metro" />
<spring:url value="/resources/css/metro-schemes.css" var="metroschemes" />
<spring:url value="/resources/css/metro-icons.css" var="metroicons" />
```

```
<link href="${metro}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="${metroschemes}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="${metroicons}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="${jquery}"></script>
```

Comment: already  my web pages and forms are loading and application working fine. but css and js wont applying to web pages

Comment: Did you checked your browser console? Any network errors like `404` for css or js?

Comment: @Arvind yes i get 404 for all css and js

Comment: in console it shows the correct path  /clickApp/resources/css/metro.css

Comment: @Arvind Still it doesn't work. is there anything i need to add web.xml about resources?

Comment: is resources folder in the WEB-INF or at the same level of WEB-INF?

Comment: please check this link :http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Comment: @kswaughs i check that tutorial also ,  resource folder is not inside the WEB-INF, its in the webapp .  still its not working .  thx

Comment: all jsp files are inside the  WEB-INF -> jsp  folder

Comment: can u try directly accessing ur .css on web browser like 'http : //server:port/appname/resources/css/metro.css'. if it is working then compare with that url path shown in view source of browser.

Comment: when i have clean and build the project again, it works fine now. thx for the help @kswaughs